# SQL Table Variable to take correct path if value in column 1 is 0 or Null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, table-variable

I need to make changes to database in bulk from information provided on a spreadsheet.

At the moment the Table Variable values are added manually, but the hope is to do this automatically from an existing Excel front end (It's a Legacy Application that isn't worth completely re-developing)

I've created the script so that Amendments to a table in SQL can be done in one Execute, the problem I ave is checking where the code should insert a new record to the database.

With amendments there is an Old Ref which is updated to a New Ref, so all columns of the Table variable contain values.

With New records there is only a New Ref so the Old Ref will be  Blank, 0 or Null (whichever it needs to be for the code.)

Here is what I have so far: (I've substituted in a 'Print' for each branch rather than showing the rest of the code which is quite long.

```
 @T_VAR TABLE (
 OldRef int,
 NewRef int,
 Name varchar(255),
 CustGp varchar(55),
 DelGp varchar(55),
 )

 ---BULK INSERT VALUES TO TABLE VARIABLE---
 INSERT INTO @T_VAR (
 OldRef,
 NewRef,
 Name,
 CustGp,
 DelGp
 )
 Values 
 --------//**ENTER VALUES HERE**//--------
 (1001,2010,'TestUpdate01','Group 1','Delivery 1'),
 (NULL,2012,'TestUpdate02','Group 2','Delivery 1'),
 (1547,2018,'TestUpdate03','Group 1','Delivery 3'),
 (NULL,2022,'TestUpdate04','Group 3','Delivery 1'),
 (1752,2050,'TestUpdate05','Group 1','Delivery 2')


 -----CHECK IF VARIABLE OldREF IS 0/NULL (Is this a New Record or an Amendment?)----

 IF (Select OldRef from @T_VAR) IS NULL

 Print 'Follow script to Insert New Record'

 else

 print 'Follow script to Amend Existing Record'
```

When running this I get the following error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The code needs to go through each row and then divert it down the correct path- If this is possible.

I know the rest of the code works for just amendments as it's been tested.

Any help that can be given in resolving this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `OldRef` isn't a "variable".  It is a column in the table.  It is totally unclear what you are trying to do, but the message seems quite clear.

Comment: "The code needs to go through each row" is not what you've written. Without a `top` or `where` clause your `select` statement returns the value of `OldRef` for _all_ of the rows. You could use a, gulp, _cursor_ to go through the table RBAR. Or it may be a matter of using an `insert ... select ... where not exists ...;`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm new to SQL so sorry if  terminology is off.  Done a bit of reading and think a Loop might be best   I've not used Loops before so this will be a good learning experience.  Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?  Also, whilst the script to amend the records in the table is quite simple, the script to insert a new record is a bit more difficult as it looks for existing References to make sure that the reference is unique, Does this mean I'll have to do a Loop for each If query, Select/Update and Insert statement, or can I just run the loop once?

Comment: In the world of SQL you should be thinking in terms of _set_ operations, not procedural code to process one row at a time. A single [`merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement can handle inserting, updating and deleting data in one table based on the contents of another table. As a rule, the last thing you want to consider is a `cursor` in a loop.

Comment: OK, I can see now where that helps to a point, but I'm struggling to see where I would identify that the OldRef is 0 or Null, or is it as simple as `Merge INTO Table2 T2 USING  @T_VAR Tv  ON (Tv.OldRef = 0) WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT (T2.NewRef, T2.Name) VALUES (Tv.NewRef, Tv.Name)?    Also, I have a couple of other IF query's after this where the NewRef is not matched, how would I transition to these?

Comment: The `on` clause is used to `join` the two tables. (I still haven't puzzled out quite what you're trying to do.) If you are trying to match corresponding rows based on `Name`, `CustGp` and `DelGp` you would need `... on Tv.Name = T2.Name and Tv.CustGp = T2.CustGp and Tv.DelGp = T2.DelGp`. Use `when matched` to update the `OldRef` and/or `NewRef` from `Tv` to `T2`. Use `when not matched` to insert rows from `Tv` that have no corresponding row in `T2`. (I'm guessing here. Your example isn't very complete.)

Comment: Im trying to create a single code to update a table for various instances   Currently done one at a time which takes couple hours as have to manually update the variables, i.e. OldRef, NewRef, ProjectName, CGID, GGID.   I was hoping to be able to use the spreadsheet we have to concatenate the data into a column and then just copy/paste the lot into the script, using this data to create the table variable.  The problem is the current code uses a few 'If Exists' statements.  So, IF Exists OldRef = 0 then we send it down one route,  Then this goes to If Exists NewRef = Ref in Table Update Name.